# KDE to Raster conversion fails when eval.points are specified

Tags: r

I want to match a kernel density layer's {ks} raster dimensions to kriged surface {spatial} and have run into an error.  The code demonstrates:

```
require(ks)
require(raster)
require(spatial)
data(topo, package="MASS")
topo.kr = surf.gls(2, expcov, topo, d=0.7)
krig_ras = raster(prmat(topo.kr, 0, 6.5, 0, 6.5, 50))

kd = kde(topo[,1:2])
kde_ras = raster(kd) # works ok

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(krig_ras); title('krig')
plot(kde_ras); title('kde')
```

[image]

As you can see the dimensions don't match as kde has added a border (see also `setMinMax(krig_ras); setMinMax(kde_ras)`).  But we can specify eval.points:

```
pts = as.data.frame(krig_ras, xy=TRUE)
kd2 = kde(topo[,1:2], eval.points = pts[,1:2])
kde_ras2 = raster(kd2)
```

The last returns the error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘raster’ for signature ‘"numeric"’
```

This [R-sig-geo page](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2010-December/010232.html) seems to cover the same error, but I can't figure out if this is the same cause - numeric layerNames. Looking at the names/str for `kd2` doesn't suggest anything.  Grateful for assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, you would like something like that:

```
kde_ras2 <- krig_ras
kde_ras2 <- setValues(kde_ras2, kd2$estimate)
```

[image]